# Visual Studio & shared dll issue on vb.net assembly: unable to load referenced library

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, build, reference

I've a problem on Visual Studio that drive me crazy.

I have two solutions (A,B) that include more vb.net assembly. On post-build event of every assembly of solution A there is a script that copy the output dll to an external folder that contains all builded dll.

Every assembly of the solution B have a reference to dll in the external folder.

And this is the problem...

When the solutions are both opened, if I build the solution A, the solution B seems lost every reference, so If I try to build solution B it prints some "unable to load referenced library" errors. This doesn't happen always, but often. So, I have to close the solution B and re-open it and then it build without any problem.

I noticed that this behavior occurs only with vb.net assembly, other assembly based on C# work perfectly.

I use Visual Studio 2010 and the assemblies are based on .NET 4.0

Can you help me?

Comment: I've found the same issue going back to VS 2005. Clicking Refresh on the problem DLL refrernce does not always solve the problem for me. Closing and reopening VS always works but is obviously a pain. I can also confirm the same difference between C# and VB.Net, as the problem does not seem to occur if the referencing project uses C#.

Comment: I've found a temporary workaround to avoid problem...on post build script as last command I run "attrib -A *.dll" on folder that contains all dll and in this way, seems work.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the problem "referenced DLL" and then click refresh.